# How does the processor know where to go when an exception is thrown?

Tags: windows, exception

How does my processor decide what code to execute upon hitting an exception?

Is the address of the exception handler stored somewhere on the stack or in a register? Is exception handling done by Windows in a way that is opaque to “conventional” developers or does Windows support implementation of exception handlers by third party developers?

Comment: It depends on what kind of exception you're talking about. Are you talking about C++/C#/JavaScript "throw" exceptions? Or are you talking about processor exceptions like "access violation"? For processor exceptions, the operating system has configured the processor to say "If a processor exception occurs, let me know". The operating system then figures out what to do next.

Comment: In 32-bit code, fs:[0] has a function pointer to the exception handler.  Typically put there on entry of a function that uses `try`.  In 64-bit code, the compiler generates a table that maps a code address range to an exception handler, typically the range covered by `try/catch`.  You can write your own SEH handler with the MSVC [`__try/__except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/try-except-statement?view=msvc-170) keywords.  VM environments as used in languages like Python, Java, C# have their own proprietary mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

I presume we are talking about CPU level exceptions - access violation, invalid instruction, division by zero and such. For those, there is a register in the CPU that stores the address of a certain data structure (the interrupt descriptor table, IDT) that contains exception handler addresses. The IDT is maintained by the OS kernel and is not visible to the userland code. The handlers for exceptions are also provided by the OS kernel.

That was the Intel x86/x86-64 story; Windows also runs on ARM. On ARM CPUs, control is passed to a handler in the low portion of memory (addresses 0x00000000 and up). The interrupt type is an index into the table of handlers ("the vector table"). Each handler is 4 bytes long, so it's usually a `jmp` command. The target of the jump is the real handler, provided by the OS. The OS makes sure the vector table is off limits to the userland code.

C++/Java/C#/Python exceptions are a whole different story.

---

Note inspired by the "how do I modify IDT" comment: I am 99% sure that whatever you are trying to accomplish doesn't need that. There are all kinds of higher level interrupt driven mechanisms in Windows; chances are whatever you are trying to do with exceptions can be accomplished *sans* messing with the IDT. For one thing, read up about `__try`/`__catch`, which is distinct from C++ `try`/`catch`. Then about vectored exception handling.

Comment: C++.. exceptions - api (ZwRaiseException ) called, which transfer execution to kernel, to the same routine which called in case cpu exception ( access violation) then process is common

Comment: Where exactly is the IDT stored? I presume it is in kernel virtual memory. And how does the IDT know what to do given an interrupt? Presumably some kind of key is loaded into a register or pushed to the stack before calling the interrupt handler right? Or is there a different interrupt function called for each type of exception? If we presume I have already bypassed PatchGuard how can I modify the IDT?

Comment: IDT is kept in a chunk of memory that only the kernel has access to. The IDT has a well known structure, described in the CPU docs; It's the CPU itself that knows how to interpret it. Yes, different exception types correspond to different interrupt numbers. Interrupt processing is a long story, unfit for an SO answer; consider reading the Intel CPU manual. Then something about Windows kernel driver development.

Comment: @RealName: Note that IDT is an x86 / x86-64 thing.  Other ISAs like AArch64 have a similar table of code pointers that the CPU reads when it encounters a page fault or something, but it has a different name.  But as Seva says, under Windows specifically, you have SEH to have the kernel run code in your process when it triggers a hardware exception.  I think serving a similar purpose to POSIX signal handler like catching SIGSEGV or SIGILL.